# Create object from environment, to use in loop

Tags: r, loops

I would like to create an object from the objects listed in the environment, to use this object in a loop, however, I am not successful.

For example, let's say I have an object in the environment called `data`, so:

```
ls()[2]
[1] "date"
```

To create an object called `data2008` from `data` in the environment, I'm trying to:

```
assign(sprintf('data%i', 2008),
        subset(ls()[2], `TEST`!=1015
               &`TEST`!=2011
               &`TEST`!=1023
               &`TEST`!=1031))
```

However, I get:

Error in subset.default(ls()[], 'TEST' != 1015 & 'TEST' != 2011 & :
object 'TEST' not found

I'm using `sprintf('data%i', 2008)` in `assign` because I need to use this in a loop. How can I proceed? I thank the help of all you.

Comment: I think you are looking for `get` - `get(ls()[2])` instead of just `ls()[2]`

Comment: It worked, thankful @Ronak Shah. Could you explain what `get` does?